# What would physics look like if light were not constant in all reference frames?

Tags: special-relativity, visible-light, string-theory

Is there a more fundamental theory that explains why speed of light must be constant in all reference frames? This seems like such a huge premise but I've never heard why it must be true, only that it is. Therefore, I have two questions:

0. Is there some reason that light must be constant in all reference frames? Would there be some sort of contradiction with other laws of physics if light were not constant?
1. How would different aspects of physics look like / feel (i.e. accelerating/decelerating and approaching the speed of light) without constant light reference frames?
2. I know people will say that at a certain point physics hits "bedrock", but I have recently read that some unrelated constraints in string theory also impose constraints on the gravitational constant or the size of electrons, etc., which suggests a consistent / self-reliant theory of physics may be out there, where every aspect of physics is reliant on other aspects. Is there any indication that topics in string theory may rely on light as a constant in all reference frames?

Comment: Your question title and question body do not match

Comment: Either the universe has a maximum speed or it doesn't. A universe with no maximum speed looks like the traditional Newtonian universe. A universe with a maximum speed looks like the universe of relativity: the maximum speed must be the same in all reference frames (otherwise it isn't a maximum!). It happens that light moves at that maximum speed, and for historical reasons it's called the "speed of light", but "speed of gravity" or "speed of causality" would be better names for c.

Answer (score 1):

We don't really know why things are, fundamentally. Even if there were a deeper explanation known (I don't think there is), eventually you would get to the point "because it matched experiment". The only question one is guaranteed an answer to in science is "how do you know?". As for how do you know, we have done experiments, and whoa - light moves the same speed in every reference frame! It's mind-boggling, and we can only wonder why. There is some degree of mystery which the scientific method is incapable of resolving.